# Undefined reference question

Tags: c++

When I try compiling this:

```
#include "OriAudioCache.hpp"

int main()
{
    System *audioSystem(0);
    FMOD_RESULT result;
    result = System_Create(&audioSystem);
    FMOD_CHECK_STATE(result);
    OriAudioCache cache(audioSystem, 20);
    string title("Ambitious Girl");
    string path("/home/findrzkeeprz/Desktop/Resources/The_Ambitious_Girl.mp3");
    cache.LoadSound(title, path, Default);
    vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(cache.FindSound(title));
    cache.PlaySound(v_iter->sound());
}
```

Which uses these files:
OriAudioCache.hpp

```
#ifndef ORI_AUDIO_CACHE_HPP_
#define ORI_AUDIO_CACHE_HPP_

#include "OriSound.hpp"
#include "OriChannel.hpp"

class OriAudioCache
{
    public:
         OriAudioCache(System *audioSystem, int maxChannels);

        ~OriAudioCache()
        {
            vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(audioCache_.begin());
            for(; v_iter != audioCache_.end(); ++v_iter)
            {
                v_iter->~OriSound();
            }
                delete audioSystem_;
        }

        void LoadSound(string const& title, string const& path, AudioLoadMode mode);
        vector<OriSound>::iterator FindSound(string const& title);
        void RemoveSound(string const& title);
        void PlaySound(Sound* sound);
        vector<OriChannel>::iterator RequestChannel(bool &allocStatus, FMOD_CHANNELINDEX &allocMode);
        void ReleaseChannel(Channel *channel);

    private:
        void inline SortChannels() {sort(channels_.begin(),channels_.end());}

        vector<OriSound> audioCache_;
        vector<OriChannel> channels_;
        System *audioSystem_;
};

#endif
```

and OriAudioCache.cpp

```
#include "OriAudioCache.hpp"

OriAudioCache::OriAudioCache(System *audioSystem, int maxChannels)
        :audioSystem_(audioSystem), channels_(maxChannels){}

void OriAudioCache::LoadSound(string const& title, string const& path, AudioLoadMode mode)
{
    OriSound sound(title, path, audioSystem_, mode);
    vector<OriSound>::iterator pos =lower_bound(audioCache_.begin(), audioCache_.end(), sound);
    audioCache_.insert(pos, sound);
}

vector<OriSound>::iterator OriAudioCache::FindSound(string const& title)
{
    vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(audioCache_.begin());
    for(; v_iter != audioCache_.end(); ++v_iter) //Would better if I could use a binary search here
    {
        if(v_iter->title() == title) return v_iter;
        else continue;
    }
    return audioCache_.end(); 
}
void OriAudioCache::RemoveSound(string const& title)
{
    vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(audioCache_.begin());
    for(; v_iter != audioCache_.end(); ++v_iter) //Would better if I could use a binary search here
    {
        if(v_iter->title() == title) audioCache_.erase(v_iter);
        else continue;
    }
}

void OriAudioCache::PlaySound(Sound* sound)
{
    bool channelAlloc(false);
    FMOD_CHANNELINDEX allocMode = FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE;
    vector<OriChannel>::iterator oriChannel = RequestChannel(channelAlloc, allocMode);
    if(channelAlloc)
    {
        FMOD_RESULT result;
        Channel *chnl = oriChannel->channel();
        result = audioSystem_->playSound(allocMode, sound, false, &chnl);
        FMOD_CHECK_STATE(result);
        bool isPlaying(false);
        chnl->isPlaying(&isPlaying);

        while(isPlaying)
        {
            chnl->isPlaying(&isPlaying);
        }

        bool paused(false);
        chnl->getPaused(&paused);
        if(!paused)
        {
            ReleaseChannel(chnl);
        }
        SortChannels(); //sort channels, reoder for channel requests
    }
}

vector<OriChannel>::iterator OriAudioCache::RequestChannel(bool &allocStatus, FMOD_CHANNELINDEX &allocMode)
{
    vector<OriChannel>::iterator vOri_iter(channels_.begin());
    if(vOri_iter->status() == false)
    {
        if(vOri_iter->channel() == 0) 
        {
            allocMode = FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE;
            vOri_iter->setStatus(true); // flag channel as being used
            return vOri_iter;
        }
        else allocMode = FMOD_CHANNEL_REUSE;
        vOri_iter->setStatus(true); // flag channel as being used
        return vOri_iter;
    }
    else return channels_.end();
}

void OriAudioCache::ReleaseChannel(Channel *channel)
{
    bool playing(false);
    bool paused(false);
    channel->isPlaying(&playing);
    channel->getPaused(&paused);
    if(!playing && !paused)
    {
        vector<OriChannel>::iterator vOri_iter(channels_.begin());
        for(; vOri_iter != channels_.end(); ++vOri_iter)
        {
            if(vOri_iter->channel() == channel) vOri_iter->setStatus(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I get undefined reference errors:

```
findrzkeeprz@Aardvak:~/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio$ make
    g++ -ggdb -I../../ -I../../Engine -I../../Include -I../../Public -o audio main.cpp ../../Libraries/FMODEX/libfmodex.so
    /tmp/cctNhPVy.o: In function `main':
    /home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `OriAudioCache::OriAudioCache(FMOD::System*, int)'
    /home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `OriAudioCache::LoadSound(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, AudioLoadMode)'
    /home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `OriAudioCache::FindSound(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
    /home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `OriAudioCache::PlaySound(FMOD::Sound*)'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [audio] Error 1
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can we see OriAudioCache.hpp?

Comment: it's in the second code segment.

Comment: Where is the declaration for SystemCreate()?

Comment: It's within fmod.hpp. I have that included in OriSound.hpp which in turn is included in OriAudioCache.hpp.

Answer (score 1):

You're compiling OriAudioCache.hpp, when you should be compiling OriAudioCache.cpp, that's assuming that file that contains the implementation.

Comment: when I compile with OriAudioCache.cpp I get multiple implementation errors. I think that's because the main file also includes OriAudioCache.hpp.

Comment: Well then the solution is to get rid of the multiple definitions, not to avoid compiling part of your code! You should be able to include a header as many times as you want and not get multiple definition errors. It looks like you've got the include guards part right, so it's not immediately obvious what these errors would be about, unless you post them. I would recommend asking a new question about the multiple-definition errors you get when you try to compile OriAudioCache.cpp along with the rest of the code. That's the real problem you're having.

Comment: Done, here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495984/multiple-definitions-question

Answer (score 0):

In general, the term "Undefined reference" from a compiler (actually the linker) means that some code fragment is accessing a symbol that the linker could not find.

### Common causes of these errors:

- Source file containing the definition
  is not included in the build process.
- A source fragment (code lines) were
  not removed.
- A header file (class declaration)
  declares the given method or symbol (which was not removed or needs to be implemented).
- Incorrect or missing scope resolution
  operator (`namespace` issue).
- Build process using wrong version of
  source files (e.g. file not checked
  into CMS.).

Most cases of these errors are not about the C++ reference operator nor dereferencing pointers.

### Solutions:

- Code review by independent eye(s).
- Code inspection tools:  Cppcheck,
  Valgrind, Klocwork, etc.
- Make fewer changes, compiler more
  often.
- Use [Test Driven Development](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html). ;-)