# multiple definitions question

Tags: c++

This question is as a result of [Undefined reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495422/undefined-reference-question).

When I try compiling this:

```
#include "OriAudioCache.hpp"

    int main()
    {
        System *audioSystem(0);
        FMOD_RESULT result;
        result = System_Create(&audioSystem);
        FMOD_CHECK_STATE(result);
        OriAudioCache cache(audioSystem, 20);
        string title("Ambitious Girl");
        string path("/home/findrzkeeprz/Desktop/Resources/The_Ambitious_Girl.mp3");
        cache.LoadSound(title, path, Default);
        vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(cache.FindSound(title));
        cache.PlaySound(v_iter->sound());
    }
```

which uses these files (directly or indirectly):
OriAudioCache.hpp

```
#ifndef ORI_AUDIO_CACHE_HPP_
#define ORI_AUDIO_CACHE_HPP_

#include "OriSound.hpp"
#include "OriChannel.hpp"

class OriAudioCache
{
    public:
         OriAudioCache(System *audioSystem, int maxChannels);

        ~OriAudioCache()
        {
            vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(audioCache_.begin());
            for(; v_iter != audioCache_.end(); ++v_iter)
            {
                v_iter->~OriSound();
            }
                delete audioSystem_;
        }

        void LoadSound(string const& title, string const& path, AudioLoadMode mode);
        vector<OriSound>::iterator FindSound(string const& title);
        void RemoveSound(string const& title);
        void PlaySound(Sound* sound);
        vector<OriChannel>::iterator RequestChannel(bool &allocStatus, FMOD_CHANNELINDEX &allocMode);
        void ReleaseChannel(Channel *channel);

    private:
        void inline SortChannels() {sort(channels_.begin(),channels_.end());}

        vector<OriSound> audioCache_;
        vector<OriChannel> channels_;
        System *audioSystem_;
};

#endif
```

OriAudioCache.cpp

```
#include "OriAudioCache.hpp"

OriAudioCache::OriAudioCache(System *audioSystem, int maxChannels)
        :audioSystem_(audioSystem), channels_(maxChannels){}

void OriAudioCache::LoadSound(string const& title, string const& path, AudioLoadMode mode)
{
    OriSound sound(title, path, audioSystem_, mode);
    vector<OriSound>::iterator pos =lower_bound(audioCache_.begin(), audioCache_.end(), sound);
    audioCache_.insert(pos, sound);
}

vector<OriSound>::iterator OriAudioCache::FindSound(string const& title)
{
    vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(audioCache_.begin());
    for(; v_iter != audioCache_.end(); ++v_iter) //Would better if I could use a binary search here
    {
        if(v_iter->title() == title) return v_iter;
        else continue;
    }
    return audioCache_.end(); 
}
void OriAudioCache::RemoveSound(string const& title)
{
    vector<OriSound>::iterator v_iter(audioCache_.begin());
    for(; v_iter != audioCache_.end(); ++v_iter) //Would better if I could use a binary search here
    {
        if(v_iter->title() == title) audioCache_.erase(v_iter);
        else continue;
    }
}

void OriAudioCache::PlaySound(Sound* sound)
{
    bool channelAlloc(false);
    FMOD_CHANNELINDEX allocMode = FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE;
    vector<OriChannel>::iterator oriChannel = RequestChannel(channelAlloc, allocMode);
    if(channelAlloc)
    {
        FMOD_RESULT result;
        Channel *chnl = oriChannel->channel();
        result = audioSystem_->playSound(allocMode, sound, false, &chnl);
        FMOD_CHECK_STATE(result);
        bool isPlaying(false);
        chnl->isPlaying(&isPlaying);

        while(isPlaying)
        {
            chnl->isPlaying(&isPlaying);
        }

        bool paused(false);
        chnl->getPaused(&paused);
        if(!paused)
        {
            ReleaseChannel(chnl);
        }
        SortChannels(); //sort channels, reoder for channel requests
    }
}

vector<OriChannel>::iterator OriAudioCache::RequestChannel(bool &allocStatus, FMOD_CHANNELINDEX &allocMode)
{
    vector<OriChannel>::iterator vOri_iter(channels_.begin());
    if(vOri_iter->status() == false)
    {
        if(vOri_iter->channel() == 0) 
        {
            allocMode = FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE;
            vOri_iter->setStatus(true); // flag channel as being used
            return vOri_iter;
        }
        else allocMode = FMOD_CHANNEL_REUSE;
        vOri_iter->setStatus(true); // flag channel as being used
        return vOri_iter;
    }
    else return channels_.end();
}

void OriAudioCache::ReleaseChannel(Channel *channel)
{
    bool playing(false);
    bool paused(false);
    channel->isPlaying(&playing);
    channel->getPaused(&paused);
    if(!playing && !paused)
    {
        vector<OriChannel>::iterator vOri_iter(channels_.begin());
        for(; vOri_iter != channels_.end(); ++vOri_iter)
        {
            if(vOri_iter->channel() == channel) vOri_iter->setStatus(false);
        }
    }
}
```

OriSound.hpp

```
#ifndef ORI_SOUND_HPP_
#define ORI_SOUND_HPP_

#include "Public/ThirdParty.hpp"
#include "Public/Public.hpp"

class OriSound
{
    public:
        OriSound()
            :title_(), path_(), sound_(0)
        {}

        OriSound(string const& title, string const& path, System* const& audioSystem, AudioLoadMode mode)
            : title_(title), path_(path)
        {
            FMOD_RESULT result;
            audioSystem->createSound(path.c_str(), mode, 0, &sound_);
            FMOD_CHECK_STATE(result);
        }

        ~OriSound()
        {
            delete sound_;
        }

        string title() const { return title_;}
        string path() const {return path_;}
        Sound *sound() const {return sound_;}

    private:
        string title_;
        string path_;
        Sound *sound_;
};

bool operator<(OriSound const& lhs, OriSound const& rhs)
{
    int result = (lhs.title()).compare(rhs.title());
    if(result == 0) return false;
    else if(result < 0 ) return true;
    else return false;
}
#endif
```

OriChannel.hpp

```
#ifndef ORI_CHANNEL_HPP_
#define ORI_CHANNEL_HPP_

#include "Public/Public.hpp"

class OriChannel
{
    public:
        OriChannel()
            :status_(false), channel_(0)
        {}

        bool status() const {return status_;}
        Channel* channel() const {return channel_;}
        void setStatus(bool value) { status_ = value;}

    private:
        bool status_;
        Channel *channel_;
};

bool operator<(OriChannel const& lhs, OriChannel const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.status() < rhs.status();
}


#endif
```

Public.hpp

```
#ifndef PUBLIC_HPP_
#define PUBLIC_HPP_

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#endif
```

ThirdParty.hpp

```
#ifndef THIRD_PARTY_HPP_
#define THIRD_PARTY_HPP_

#include "FMODEX/fmod_errors.h"
#include "FMODEX/fmod.hpp"

#include "Public/Public.hpp"

using namespace FMOD;

void FMOD_CHECK_STATE(FMOD_RESULT result)
{
    if (result != FMOD_OK)
    {
        cout << "FMOD error! (" << result << ")" << FMOD_ErrorString(result) << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}

typedef enum
{
    Default = FMOD_DEFAULT,
    Hardware_2D_CreateStream = FMOD_HARDWARE | FMOD_2D | FMOD_CREATESTREAM ,
    Hardware_2D_CreateSample = FMOD_HARDWARE | FMOD_2D | FMOD_CREATESAMPLE,
    Hardware_3D_CreateStream = FMOD_HARDWARE | FMOD_3D | FMOD_CREATESTREAM ,
    Hardware_3D_CreateSample = FMOD_HARDWARE | FMOD_3D | FMOD_CREATESAMPLE,
    Software_2D = FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_2D,
    Software_2D_CreateStream = FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_2D | FMOD_CREATESTREAM ,
    Software_2D_CreateSample = FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_2D | FMOD_CREATESAMPLE,
    Software_2D_CreateCompressedSample = FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_2D | FMOD_CREATECOMPRESSEDSAMPLE,
    Software_3D_CreateStream = FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_3D | FMOD_CREATESTREAM ,
    Software_3D_CreateSample = FMOD_HARDWARE | FMOD_3D | FMOD_CREATESAMPLE,
    Software_3D_CreateCompressedSample = FMOD_SOFTWARE | FMOD_3D | FMOD_CREATECOMPRESSEDSAMPLE
}AudioLoadMode;
#endif
```

I get multiple definition errors:

```
findrzkeeprz@Aardvak:~/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio$ make
g++ -ggdb -I../../ -I../../Engine -I../../Include -I../../Public -o audio OriAudioCache.cpp main.cpp ../../Libraries/FMODEX/libfmodex.so
/tmp/ccWiUARs.o: In function `FMOD_CHECK_STATE(FMOD_RESULT)':
/home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/../../Public/ThirdParty.hpp:12: multiple definition of `FMOD_CHECK_STATE(FMOD_RESULT)'
/tmp/ccF7Dod3.o:/home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/../../Public/ThirdParty.hpp:12: first defined here
/tmp/ccWiUARs.o: In function `operator<(OriSound const&, OriSound const&)':
/home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/OriSound.hpp:38: multiple definition of `operator<(OriSound const&, OriSound const&)'
/tmp/ccF7Dod3.o:/home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/OriSound.hpp:38: first defined here
/tmp/ccWiUARs.o: In function `operator<(OriChannel const&, OriChannel const&)':
/home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/OriChannel.hpp:23: multiple definition of `operator<(OriChannel const&, OriChannel const&)'
/tmp/ccF7Dod3.o:/home/findrzkeeprz/Documents/Chidori/Engine/Audio/OriChannel.hpp:23: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [audio] Error 1
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: The file 'Public.hpp' is a bad idea. 'using namespace X' in a header file is a (very) bad idea as it forces everybody that uses the header file to bring it all into stranded stuff into the global namespace.

Comment: I'm really, really bemused by how the FMOD library prefixes all of its symbols with `FMOD_` *and* apparently puts them in an `FMOD` namespace.  Seriously, use one or the other. I'd recommend the namespace; then you can get rid of `using namespace FMOD;` and things like `FMOD_OK` become `FMOD::OK`.  If your shop says *"ZOMG an extra character!"* then use the `FMOD_` prefix instead.

Comment: You're right. I should get rid of that, thanks.

Comment: Oh, and one other problem with `Public.hpp`: change it and you have to rebuild everything, possibly breaking something you aren't working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
bool operator<(OriSound const& lhs, OriSound const& rhs)
```

function needs to be marked `inline` or it needs to be implemented in a .cpp with only the declaration inthe .hpp file.

```
inline
bool operator<(OriSound const& lhs, OriSound const& rhs)
{
    // ....
}
```

or:

```
// in OriSound.hpp
bool operator<(OriSound const& lhs, OriSound const& rhs);

// in OriSound.cpp
bool operator<(OriSound const& lhs, OriSound const& rhs)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Same with 'FMOD_CHECK_STATE()'

Comment: I applied your answer to FMOD_CHECK_STATE as well, it fixed everything. Thanks.